# How to get data from html with thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf to send a message by mail, I use Contex () to set variables that have user fields. What is the problem? The problem is that when you send data from a template from the mail, the entire html code is sent, but you just need a message. I think looking at the code will be clearer

```
 Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("name", user.getUsername());
    context.setVariable("activationCode", user.getActivationCode());
    MvcConfig mvcConfig = new MvcConfig();
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = mvcConfig.templateEngine();
    String text = templateEngine.process("email-template",context);
    if (!org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
        //TODO: move to template

        mailSenderService.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", text);
    }




@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(new UrlTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

[image]

in this form comes in the mail, but it should be something like this
Hello Dear, laza
Welcome.Please visit http://aa.ru/activate-account/blalblalbla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message,String content) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setContent(content, "HTML5");
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    helper.setFrom(username);
    helper.setTo(emailTo);
    helper.setText(message,true);
    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);}
```

i add Content in method for sending mail, it solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Please change your `templateEngine()` method as follows:

```
@Bean
public ITemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine() {
   SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
   ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
   templateResolver.setPrefix("/");
   templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
   templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML); // Important line is here for HTML!!!
   templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
   templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
   return templateEngine;
}
```

Please note the `TemplateMode.HTML` line

Comment: dont change anything, the same result

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html

```
private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
        templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

And

```
    @Bean
        public TemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {
            final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
     // Resolver for HTML emails (except the editable one)
            templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
...
}
```

Comment: type conflict ClassLoaderTemplateResolver and ITemplateResolver

Comment: dont find template

Comment: U are the only one who can do that ;)